# I need help with a shower handle replacement. I don't know what type of valve this is. I just want to replace the trim

Tags: bathroom, shower

I attached a photo of the old valve in one of my rentals. I have bought several handle replacements but none of them match. I thought it was pressure balancing, but apparently it's not or it's an older type.

Does anyone know what this is and how I can find a black trim replacement for it?

[image]

Comment: if you clean it you might see the lebel

Comment: "how I can find a black trim replacement" is a shopping question and those are explicitly off-topic here. Please [edit] to remove that part (as you'd find it the same way you'd find a pair of black shoes or a black t-shirt - by going shopping).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a very old MOEN piece. The ball can be removed by using the 2 cut out flats to turn the ring counterclockwise.

You can find a replacement ball with new seals and springs in a kit.  ( The seals and springs are found inside when you remove the ball)  That repair kit can then be matched to a trim kit that works with it.

Probably better results will be had at a plumbing supply rather than a big box.
You will have to do shopping on your own.

Comment: Thank you! I think I found it, it's like the 600 series Delta.